# Product between a functor and a distributor

Tags: category-theory

Given a distributor $\phi\colon \mathbf{A}\not\rightarrow \bf B$ and a functor $F\colon \bf B\to X$ I can define $F\otimes\phi$ to be the functor $\bf A\to X$ given by $\text{Lan}_{y}F\circ\widehat{\phi}$, where $\widehat\phi\colon \bf B\to\widehat A$ is the adjunct of $\phi$ in the obvious bijection. More explicitly, 
$$
F\otimes\phi(a) = \int^b {\rm Nat}(y_b,\phi(-,a))\cdot Fb\cong \int^b \phi(b,a)\cdot Fb
$$
Exploiting this definition, several things can be proved:

1. $F\otimes\hom\cong F$;
2. If $\mathbf{C}\stackrel{\psi}{\not\rightarrow}\mathbf A\stackrel{\phi}{\not\rightarrow} \mathbf B\xrightarrow{F}\mathbf X$, then $F\otimes(\phi\psi)\cong (F\otimes \phi)\otimes\psi$.

I am now interested in this question: given a diagram like $\mathbf A\stackrel{\phi}{\not\rightarrow}\mathbf B\xrightarrow{F}\mathbf X\stackrel{\psi}{\not\rightarrow}\mathbf C\xrightarrow{G}\mathbf Y$, does $(G\otimes\psi)\circ (F\otimes\phi)$ enjoy some useful properties?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, your product $F \otimes \phi$ is a well-known concept in enriched category theory: it is just the colimit of $F$ weighted by $\phi$, usually denoted by $\phi \star F$ or $\phi \cdot F$. Actually, in Kelly's [*Basic concepts of enriched category theory*](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html), this is defined only for $\mathbf{A} = 1$, but [Wood](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1982__23_3_279_0.pdf) has the general version (albeit in the more general setting of proarrow equipments).

What kind of good properties would you expect from $(\psi \star G) \circ (\phi \star F)$? When $\psi$ is cocontinuous in its covariant argument ($\mathbf{X}$), then this seems to coincide with $(\psi \otimes F_* \otimes \phi) \star G$, where $\otimes$ is composition of distributors, and $F_*$ is the image of $F$ under the embedding $\mathbf{Cat} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Dist}$, i.e., $F_*(x,b) = \mathbf{X}(x,Fb)$.